# How to prove $n$-to-$1$ mapping property for Blaschke products?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request

I have two questions regarding the Blaschke products.

1) I came across the following post

[Boundary behaviour of finite Blaschke products on the unit circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1964163/boundary-behaviour-of-finite-blaschke-products-on-the-unit-circle#comment6553483_1964163)

where it's mentioned that for any $\lambda\in \mathbb T$ (unit circle), the equation
$$B(z):=\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^n\dfrac{z-a_k}{1-\overline{a_k}z}=\lambda$$
has $n$ distinct solutions. In this equation, $a_k\in \mathbb D$ (open unit disk). 
**How to prove this?** If it's a standard result, then a reference would be welcome!

2) In an attempt to find similar questions, I came across the following

[Is a Blaschke product/rational function a covering map for a $n$-sheeted covering of $S^{1}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1840350/is-a-blaschke-product-rational-function-a-covering-map-for-a-n-sheeted-coverin)

which I think is saying the same thing in my question above. **If it is saying the same thing, what would be a good reference to understand the argument presented?**

Comment: it's proven in the post linked above: trivially by the fundamental theorem of algebra there are $n$ preimages since eliminating denominators gives a degree n-polynomial equal to zero for a fixed $|\lambda|=1$ and we know that a finite Blaschke product preserves the unit disc, its inside and its outside so the n-roots for $|\lambda|=1$ must be on the circle; the derivative not being zero on the unit circle excludes roots being equal, so we are done

Comment: I got up to the point where there are at  most $n$ roots. What trips me up is why there are exactly $n$ of them (no repetitions). You're saying this is where the derivative being nonzero on $\mathbb T$ comes in?

Comment: If there were repetitions, the derivative must be zero (a finite Blaschke product is holomorphic on the unit circle too, meaning in a neighbourhood of it and holomorphic functions with double roots have zero derivative there); but a standard computation done in the post linked above, shows the derivative has positive absolute value ($|B'(e^{i\theta})|=\Sigma{\frac{1-|a_k|^2}{|e^{i\theta}-a_k|^2}}$)

Comment: I understand. Thanks Conrad! That solves the first question.

Comment: The second question says that $B$ is a $n \to 1$ local homeomorphism and that follows because the derivative is never zero on the circle plus the compacity of the circle which means that essentially you can split the circle into n-arcs, $B$ takes same value at the ends of the arcs - you can pick it arbitrary on the circle -and maps each of them homeomorphically onto the circle when we identify the ends, so it is more-or-less equivalent to the first question (up to a little topology); https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.05444 is a great survey on the subject

Comment: Forgive me, I'm a little bit fuzzy understanding your argument cos I don't have the intuition yet. What subject should I read about to understand your argument?

Thanks for the link!

Comment: maybe a little bit about covering spaces - haven't read topology in decades so not sure what is a good up-to-date reference; for anything about finite Blaschke products per se the survey linked above is excellent both itself and its references

Comment: As far as I know, Munkres is still considered the standard text for an intro to general topology, and is quite well written.